# Por que os navegadores não implementam os protocolos PUT e DELETE do HTTP?

Tags: http, post, navegador-de-internet, get, http-métodos

Por algum motivo os navegadores de internet (Chrome, Firefox, IE, ...) decidiram apenas implementar os métodos GET e POST do protocolo HTTP.

Os demais métodos como o PUT e DELETE ficaram de fora.

Por que?

Minha dúvida surgiu por causa *[desta frase do guia oficial do Ruby on Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#how-do-forms-with-patch-put-or-delete-methods-work-questionmark)*:

> The Rails framework encourages [RESTful design](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST) of your applications, which means you'll be making a lot of "PATCH" and "DELETE" requests (besides "GET" and "POST"). However, **most browsers don't support methods other than "GET" and "POST" when it comes to submitting forms**.

Que traduzido é:

> O framework Rails encoraja o uso do [padrão REST](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST) em suas aplicações, oque significa que você fará várias requisições "PATCH" e "DELETE" (além de "GET" e "POST"). Contudo, **a maioria dos navegadores não suportam outros métodos além de "GET" e "POST" quando utilizando formulários**.

Obs.: portanto, aparentemente, esses métodos só não são suportados via tag `<form>...</form>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa resposta é mais um comentário enorme [à resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16821/por-que-os-navegadores-nao-implementam-os-protocolos-put-e-delete-do-http/16827#16827) do @carlosfigueira, mas que contém algumas informações até que interessantes.

---

Quanto a declaração de os browsers modernos implementarem os outros *HTTP Verbs*, tenho lá minhas dúvidas. Isso porque um ano atrás eu e uns colegas de fórum testamos e pelo menos o Chrome, Opera e o Safari, atualizados até então, respeitaram apenas o POST. Os outros (PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS...) eles assumiram o método GET.

Ou seja, para que você possa usufruir desses outros verbos na aplicação *server-side*, você tem duas alternativas, sendo uma delas uma pequena gambiarra pois viola a [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html):

1. Use [XHR](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest). Pró: Você pode usar qualquer verbo que precisar. Contra: Obstrusivo! Se sua Aplicação depender de JS e este não estiver disponível, ela não funciona.
2. Passe o verbo diretamente na URL ou por algum campo *hidden*.

   Por exemplo, para deletar um usuário sem suporte completo ao verbo DELETE, teríamos:

   `http://www.domain.com/management/user/delete/1`

Comment: O Ruby on Rails, para métodos que deveriam ser DELETE ou PUT, ele cria formulários POST mas com um atributo *hidden* chamado `"_method"` de valor `"DELETE"` ou `"PUT"`, que são avaliados na camada de rotas do Rails para decidir qual é o controlador/ação corretos a serem acionados.

Comment: Ou seja, ele faz mais esse trabalho para os programadores :p

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo ponto negativo, seja você quem for.

Comment: Mas a resposta do carlosfigueira diz claramente que PUT e DELETE não funcionam em forms. Isso está definido na especificação do HTML. Os 4 métodos, só em XHR mesmo.

Answer (score 6):

Isso não é verdade. Todos os navegadores modernos (i.e., IE, Chrome, Firefox, Safari que foram lançados pelo menos nos últimos 3 anos, possivelmente bem mais) suportam todos os métodos de HTTP. GET é suportado em vários escopos, como em todos os tags com um atributo `src` (e.g., `<script src="o endereço que será acessado via GET"></script>`).

Para usar os outros métodos, você normalmente usa o objeto [`XMLHttpRequest`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/), onde você define o método HTTP que quer usar via [`open()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-open%28%29-method).

Há ainda outras formas de enviar requisições HTTP pelo navegador, por exemplo num `submit` de um `<form>`. Nesse caso os navegadores não suportam métodos além de GET e POST a definição de HTML forms limita os verbos apenas a esses dois. Veja a especificação do [HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.3) ou do [HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#form-submission) para maiores detalhes.

Um problema que você talvez esteja encontrando é que existem algumas configurações de **servidores** que não suportam requisições usando PUT ou DELETE - há algumas versões atrás a configuração padrão do IIS era dessa forma (você pode habilitar os outros métodos mudando a configuração). Mas isso aí seria um problema do servidor, e não do navegador.

Comment: Atualizei minha pergunta.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta :)