# Quando devo usar função GET e quando devo usar função POST?

Tags: php, cakephp

Tenho uma dúvida e acho que é até bem "idiota" mas quando deve-se usar GET e quando deve usar POST ?

Sei que quando se usa GET o texto ou mensagem escrita em um formulário ou campo, é passado também para o link ou endereço da URL, então sei que GET não se usa por exemplo, para login ou cadastro.

Mas quais são as funcionalidades de GET e POST?

Comment: Relacionado : http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16821/por-que-os-navegadores-n%C3%A3o-implementam-os-protocolos-put-e-delete-do-http

Comment: Não é relacionado, mas agradeço a tentativa

Comment: Talvez seja duplicata de: [Quais as vantagens de se utilizar os métodos HTTP corretos?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49322/91)

Comment: [Quais são os métodos de requisição HTTP, e qual é a diferença entre eles?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9419/)

Comment: @rray se alguém que não tem medalha de ouro votar numa, e um de nós votar na outra, ficam as duas como duplicata. Eu acho que juntando seu link com o que eu passei, fica completo. Só resta alguém sem medalha de ouro "puxar a fila".

Comment: @Bacco legal essa outra pergunta, as duas como referência fica 100%.

Comment: E quem quiser completar o raciocínio, pode postar resposta nelas, cabe mais coisa lá, aí fica tudo linkado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você já sabe como cada um funciona, portanto vou dar exemplos de quando usar.

GET passa variáveis por URL, é útil para você compartilhar uma página de produto, fazer paginação, essas coisas... Ou seja, como benefício você pode reproduzir uma busca apenas copiando o URL, já que as variáveis estão nela.
Exemplo:

produto.php?produto=200 (vai exibir o produto com id 200)
Você poderia até salvar o URL como favorito, iria para o produto 200.

Com POST você não pode fazer essas coisas que eu disse acima, pois os dados são enviados no corpo da requisição HTTP, como você disse, é ideal para formulários de login, cadastro, envio de arquivos (por get não dá).

Resumindo: a diferença está principalmente na visibilidade dos dados.

Obs: a requisição GET é relativamente mais rápida, já que ela é mais simples. Na requisição POST há uma perda de tempo no encapsulamento da mensagem.

Comment: Basicamente o GET não deveria ser usado para alterar o estado da aplicação, por exemplo, apagar um recurso (meusite.com?acao=apagar_noticia&id=1), por isso ele é considerado um método "seguro", já o POST, considerado método "inseguro", pode e deve ser usado para alterar o estado da aplicação.

Answer (score 3):

O `GET` tem um limite de caracteres, variando de acordo com o navegador pois esse limite é em função do tamanho da URL. Geralmente utilizando quando se quer passar poucas informações. Além disso, como você mesmo observou, com o `GET` as informações são passadas através da URL, ficando visíveis. A função do `GET` é basicamente para se recuperar uma informação/recurso do servidor, além disso, o resultado da requisição pode ir para o cache do cliente (a URL com as informações passadas nela ficam salvas no histórico, por exemplo). É mais rápido do que o `POST`, já que as informações são enviadas via URL.
o `GET` é limitado ao envio de textos, utilizando padrão ASCII

Já o `POST` é mais seguro, visto que a URL não exibe as informações que estão sendo enviadas. Não possui limite de caracteres, sendo necessário uma conexão paralela para envio das informações.
Como é criada uma conexão para envio das informações, uma requisição `HTTP` é criada para envio. Por conta disso, neste método, as informações enviadas ficam no corpo da requisição, e assim como toda requisição `HTTP`, existem os cabeçalhos que também são enviados. É mais lenta pois há a necessidade de encapsular a mensagem para envio. 
Através do `POST` há a possibilidade de envio de informações binárias, além do envio de textos.