# Dúvida: $.ajax() ou $.get ou $.post()?

Tags: jquery

Olá!

No meu projeto, o usuário faz um cadastro inserindo usuário, e-mail, link 1(http) e link 2(http). Eu salvo esses dados em um banco de dados.

Na página verificalogin.php, eu verifico se os dados e-mail e senha estão corretos e se estiverem, eu redireciono o usuário para a página principal.html, caso contrário, redireciono para a página index.php.

Página verificalogin.php :

```html
<?php
require 'conexao.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>VerificaLogin</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function loginsucesso(){
   setTimeout("location.href='principal.html'", 3000);
  }

  function loginerro(){
   setTimeout("location.href='index.php'", 3000);
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>


<?php
session_start();
$email=$_POST['email'];
$senha=$_POST['senha'];

$querry = "SELECT * FROM bancodados WHERE email='$email' AND senha='$senha'";
$sql = mysqli_query($con,$querry) or die(mysqli_error());
$row = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
$dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
$user = $dados['user'];
$_SESSION['id'] = $user; 
$end1 = $dados["link1"];
$end2 = $dados["link2"];
$var="<br/>";
 
if ($row > 0){
 $_SESSION ['email'] = $_POST ['email'];
    $_SESSION ['senha'] = $_POST ['senha'];
    echo "<center><h3>Login realizado com sucesso!</center></h3>";
    echo "<script>loginsucesso()</script>";
} else {
 echo "<center><h3>Usuário ou senha incorretos</center></h3>";
 echo "<script>loginerro()</script>";
}

?>
```

Na página principal.html eu tenho os códigos:

```html
<?php
require 'conexao.php';
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["email"]) || !isset($_SESSION["senha"])){
 header("Location: index.php");
 exit;
} 
$usuario = array();
    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM bancodados WHERE user = $_SESSION['id']";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($con,$query1);
    while(mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado) = $row1){
    array_push($usuario,$row1);
    } 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head> 
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Exemplo numero 1</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="site">

<div id="areapessoal">
     <section>
  <figure id="fotoperfil">
   <img src="imagens/usuario.jpg" alt="Foto de Perfil">
  </figure>
     <br>
     <p><h3 id="user"><?= $usuario['id']; ?></h3></p>
     <input id="sair" type="button" onclick="location.href='logout.php';" value="Sair" />
     </section>
    </div>

<div id="links">
        <section class="icons">
        <a id="lend1" href="<?=$usuario['href1']?>"><?= $usuario['end1'] ?><img src="imagens/link1.jpg" alt="Link 1"/></a> 
  </section>
     <section class="icons">
     <a id="lend2" href="<?=$usuario['href1']?>"><?=$usuario['end2']?><img src="imagens/link2.jpg" alt="Link 2"/></a>
     </section>  
     
</body>
</html>
```

Eu preciso substituir o conteúdo da tag (h3) pela minha variável $user, e href das tag (a) por $end1 e $end2.

$user, $end1 e $end2 estão na página verificalogin.php e são variáveis PHP.

Eu tentei fazer:

```js
function loginsucesso(){
     $.get("principal.html", function(){
        $("#user").html("<?=$user?>");
        $("#end1").attr("href","<?=$end1?>");
        $("#end2").attr("href","<?=$end2?>");
      });
   setTimeout("location.href='principal.html'", 3000);
   }
```

Mas não está funcionando!!

Quem puder me ajudar eu agradeço!
Vlw!

Answer (score 7):

Esse [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/118213/quando-devo-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-get-e-quando-devo-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-post) explica quando usar GET ou POST, no JQUERY GET & POST são alias ou apelidos para o método AJAX, quando voce usa o [$.GET](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) isso é uma abreviação para:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

e o mesmo acontece para o [$.POST](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) que é uma abreviação de:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Esse erro está acontecendo, porque você está fazendo uma requisição para a página principal.html o callback do [$.GET](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) retorna os dados solicitados da página. Existem várias maneiras de você fazer isso, uma que pode ser uma solução possível é, no momento que ele verifica o login em **verificalogin.php**, salvar o id do usuário em uma variável de sessão do php *ou até o usuário inteiro com todas informações que precisa*.

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $usuarioId;
```

e Então quando ele entrasse na página principal você poderia fazer uma solicitação ao banco para listar todas as informações dele e então através do php imprimir todas as informações,

```html
<!-- 
     $usuario = array();
     $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = $_SESSION['id']";
     $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao,$query);
     while(mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado) = $row){
          array_push($usuario,$row);
     }
     
 -->
<p><h3 id="user"> <?= $usuario['id']; ?> </h3></p>
 <div id="painel">
        <section class="icons">
          <a id="end1" href="<?=$usuario['href1']?>"><?= $usuario['link1'] ?><img alt="end link 1"/></a> 
      </section>
        <section class="icons">
          <a id="end2" href="<?=$usuario['href1']?>"><?=$usuario['link2']?><img alt="end link 2"/></a> 
      </section>
```

**NÃO RECOMENDO ESCREVER QUERYS DIRETAMENTE EM UMA "VIEW"** o melhor seria que você tivesse uma API ou uma classe que cuidasse disso, mas dessa forma também irá funcionar.

E se mesmo assim você ainda preferir fazer uma requisição através do AJAX para pegar os dados do usuario então crie uma página PHP que retornará esses dados, digamos que será uma página com a query escrita acima, você poderia dá um

```
<?php echo json_encode($usuario) ?>
```

dessa forma você retornaria um [JSON](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4042/o-que-%C3%A9-json-para-que-serve-e-como-funciona) com os dados do usuário que é o formato mais leve conhecido por mim de transferência/intercâmbio de dados, e você poderia obter esses dados através do JQUERY dessa forma:

```js
function loginsucesso(){
     $.getJSON("pegaInformacoesDoUsuario.php", function(dados){
        /* verifique como vem o formato do JSON e troque pela forma correta */
        console.log(dados)
        $("#user").text(dados.user);
        $("#end1").attr("href",dados.end1);
        $("#end2").attr("href",dados.end2);
      });
}
```

Comment: Olá Reynnan, obrigado pela resposta! Depois de fazer as alterações que vc indicou, O apache deu erro de permissão 403. Foi a primeira vez que ocorreu isso. Colocando o link diretamente na tag (a) vai numa boa. Alterei os arquivos 'httpd.com' e 'httpd-vhosts.conf' para require all granted, mas continua com o mesmo erro.

Comment: pode postar seu código aqui? ou você tem algum repositório com isso?

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta e postei os dois arquivos, verificacad.php e principal.php.