# Atualizar conteúdo de um .load()

Tags: jquery, html

Gostaria de saber se é possível atualizar o conteúdo de um load.
Exemplo:

Tenho um formulário na página **"enviar_formulário.html"**

```
<form action="submeter" method="post">
<input type="text" name="nome" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Faço load desse form em **outra página**...

```
<div id="conteudoFixo">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel neque eu magna vestibulum tincidunt. Duis a lobortis felis, id pulvinar nulla. Pellentesque fermentum sollicitudin nisl, at molestie felis pretium vel. Donec tellus mauris, imperdiet sed sagittis in, consectetur quis ex.
</div>
<div id="conteudoMuda">
<button id="botaoForm">Mostrar Form</button>
</div>
```

E utilizo o **jquery** pra dar o load:

```
jQuery('#botaoForm').click(function(){ 
    jQuery('#conteudoMuda').load('/enviar_formulário.html');
});
```

O problema é que, quando dou submit no form, ele me redireciona ***(action="submeter")***. Eu gostaria de enviar os dados sem ser redirecionados.

## Nota: Não posso utilizar ajax para submeter o form.

Código do ajax:

```
/* submeter form trocar nick */
jQuery('form[name="post"]').submit( function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery.ajax({
     dataType:'html',
        type     : 'POST',
        data     : ({username_edit: jQuery("#username_edit").val(), user_rank : jQuery("#rankusren").val(), signature : jQuery("#assinaturaa").val(), profile_field_10_5 : jQuery("#profile_field_10_5").val(), user_status : jQuery("#user_status_yes").val(), user_allowpm : jQuery("#user_allowpm_yes").val(), user_allowavatar : jQuery("#user_allowavatar_yes").val(), mode : jQuery("[name='mode']").val(), agreed : jQuery("[name='agreed']").val(), id : jQuery("#idusrpnl").val()}),
        success  : function( resultado ){
            alert('Nome trocado!');
        }
    });
});
/* fim do form trocar nick */
```

## Video mostrando que o formulário não é submetico com ajax. Mas com ajax, é submetido normalmente

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JESNg-w2HUw&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Me dê uma razão válida para não usar ajax.

Comment: Estou trabalhando em uma plataforma de fórum, e ajax com POST não funciona, apenas GET

Comment: Até tentei fazer, mas ele submete o fórum sem enviar os valores, e retorna o success. Mesmo utilizando error ou fail(), continuo recebendo success

Comment: Da pra fazer com GET e enviar os dados como query string também.

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo? Vou adicionar o código que tentei na pergunta

Comment: Você quer fazer uma requisição assíncrona POST sem ser assíncrona? Não entendi.

Comment: Na realidade, fiz a pergunta pois não consegui com o ajax. Então pensei em maneiras de fazer o sistema sem. Pensei em utilizar iframe, mas não considero uma boa solução.

Comment: Por quê diz que esse POST não é assíncrono @AndersonCarlosWoss?

Comment: @LucasCosta o padrão da submissão de um formulário é uma requisição síncrona, pois o navegador é redirecionado para a página e deve esperar a resposta do servidor.

Comment: O submit é síncrono, o post com Ajax é assíncrono @Andersoncarloswoss, que foi o exemplo dele. Pode-se usar dessa forma para serializar o formulário por exemplo.

Comment: É isso que eu estou dizendo: ele disse que não pode utilizar AJAX mas quer que a requisição seja assíncrona.

Answer (score 2):

No quesito segurança GET e POST são iguais, tendo como diferença apenas que GET expõe os dados na URL e POST não, dentre algumas outras peculiaridades de semântica e estrutura.

Você poderia passar as informações via GET e recuperar (a forma como irá recuperar os dados pode depender de quem estará do outro lado) usando query string:

```
jQuery('form[name="post"]').submit( function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery.ajax({
     dataType:'html',
        type     : 'GET',
        url: 'minharl.com' + $.param($(this).serializeArray()),
        success  : function( resultado ){
            alert('Nome trocado!');
        }
    });
});
```

[$.param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) representa um objeto para se usar em query string ou requisições ajax. O resultado será algo mais ou menos como:

```
minharl.com?a%5Bone%5D=1&a%5Btwo%5D=2&
```

**Outras fontes**

[Quais são os métodos de requisição HTTP, e qual é a diferença entre eles?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9419/quais-s%c3%a3o-os-m%c3%a9todos-de-requisi%c3%a7%c3%a3o-http-e-qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-eles)

[Quando devo usar função GET e quando devo usar função POST?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/118213/quando-devo-usar-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-get-e-quando-devo-usar-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-post)

Comment: Lembrando que o servidor precisa ser capaz de responder devidamente a uma requisição GET tal como a requisição POST.

Comment: Não entendi o que quiz dizer @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: Desde já, obrigado pela resposta. Mas a plataforma utilizada não me permite fazer esta requisição.

Comment: O arquivo no lado do servidor pode estar esperando apenas uma requisição POST e não tratar devidamente uma GET. Não foi comentado sobre o lado do servidor, mas em PHP, por exemplo, se houver `if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")`, a requisição GET será ignorada.

Comment: *Estou trabalhando em uma plataforma de fórum, e ajax com POST não funciona, apenas GET*, dei a alternativa com GET devido o seu comentário @VME

Comment: @AnsersonCarlosWoss, isso responde ao que pontuou?

Comment: Não sou permitido a enviar/pegar parametros pela url. Eu também não entendo como vou fazer isso. Não sei porque consigo enviar dados pelo form normalmente mas não consigo enviar pelo ajax

Comment: O ajax pode estar sendo bloqueado pelo CORS @VME.

Comment: Quando utiliza ajax ele mostra erro de CORS no console? Porque não recebo nenhum erro. E tudo ocorre dentro do mesmo site.

Comment: Mostra sim @VME. Se não é CORS, você vai precisar aprender as configurações do tal fórum que vai receber os dados. Se não tiver autonomia nenhuma sobre ele e/ou não detalhar melhor pra nós como é essa fonte, não vai ter nenhum milagre que se faça pra comunicar com o servidor.

Comment: Obrigado pelas informações. Vou tentar o possível aqui

Comment: de nada @VME, quando tiver novidade atualize a questão =]