# Capturar Array de Json com JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html5, json

Bom dia Galera,

Sei que o enunciado da pergunta é parecido com muitas outras, porém o problema se torna um pouco diferente.

Eu tenho um controller onde filtro as informações que vem do meu BD por um Foreach para alinha as datas iguas, e trazer as linhas em um unico array para cada data, para poder colocar cada table com sua data e informçãoes.

Controller:

```
public function get()
{
    $user = $_SESSION['nome'];


    $this->load->model('trackerModel');
    $query = $this->trackerModel->get($user)->result_array();


    foreach($query as $element){
        $result[$element['date']][] = $element;
    }
```

Daí puxo ele com meu Ajax, até aí tranquilo... Porém não consigo extrair o que tem dentro de cada data array.

JSON:

```
 {
"20-08-2019":[
  {
    "id":"4",
    "hrStart":"09:00",
    "hrEnd":"12:05",
    "hrWork":"03:05",
    "nome_user":"Diego ",
    "date":"20-08-2019",
    "cliente":"Carlos",
    "projeto":"TimeSheet",
    "pacote":"TimeTrack",
    "type":"","descri":""
  },
  {
    "id":"5",
    "hrStart":"13:30",
    "hrEnd":"14:30",
    "hrWork":"01:00",
    "nome_user":"Diego ",
    "date":"20-08-2019",
    "cliente":"Carlos",
    "projeto":"TimeSheet",
    "pacote":"Pacote",
    "type":"",
    "descri":""
  }
],
"08-08-2019":[
  {
    "id":"3",
    "hrStart":"04:00",
    "hrEnd":"07:00",
    "hrWork":"03:00",
    "nome_user":"Diego ",
    "date":"08-08-2019",
    "cliente":"Marcelo",
    "projeto":"TimeSheet",
    "pacote":"Dashboard",
    "type":"","descri":""
  }
]
```

}

Tentei várias maneiras com o `for`.

JS:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'tracker/get',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){

        for (var dataIndex in data) {
            console.log(dataIndex);
            $("#table").append(`<table id="table${dataIndex}">`);
            for (j = 0; j < data[dataIndex].length; j++) {
              $(`#table${dataIndex}`).append(`
                  <tr>
                    <td>${data[dataIndex][j].hrStart}</td>
                    <td>${data[dataIndex][j].hrEnd}</td>
                    <td>${data[dataIndex][j].hrWork}</td>
                    <td>${data[dataIndex][j].nome_user}</td>
                    <td>${data[dataIndex][j].date}</td>
                  </tr>
                `);
            }
          }
          $("#exampleTable").append(`</table>`);

    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Fico grato se puderem ajudar!

Comment: Poderia postar o html reproduzi aqui e pra está ok: https://jsfiddle.net/vladwoguer/aL7oyc31/2/

Comment: Eu tentei usar desta maneira que tu reproduziu aí, meu codigo está assim, porem nenhuma informação é enviada.

Comment: Uma coisa que vi é que esse metodo não seria um GET ao inves de um POST?

Comment: Eu puxo ele do banco amigo... Qual seria a diferença ?

Comment: A diferença seria só semantica mesmo. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/118213/quando-devo-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-get-e-quando-devo-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-post

Quanto as sua pergunta, seu ```for``` está correto para o json que passou. Poderia incluir na pergunta o html que está usando? (pode ser só o componente de id="table"). Obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aconselho você a melhorar seu `json`, no `javascript` todo array associativo é um objeto então fica um pouco complicado de tratar as informações do jeito que você montou o `json`, é possível mas é meio chato.

Faça um segundo `foreach` para organizar o seu `json` da seguinte maneira.

```
$data = [];
foreach($result as $key => $value) {
    $data[] = [
        'date' => $key,
        'items' => $value
    ];
}
```

Formato do novo `json`.

```
[{"date":"20-08-2019","items":[{"id":"4","hrStart":"09 => 00","hrEnd":"12 => 05","hrWork":"03 => 05","nome_user":"Diego ","date":"20-08-2019","cliente":"Carlos","projeto":"TimeSheet","pacote":"TimeTrack","type":"","descri":""},{"id":"5","hrStart":"13 => 30","hrEnd":"14 => 30","hrWork":"01 => 00","nome_user":"Diego ","date":"20-08-2019","cliente":"Carlos","projeto":"TimeSheet","pacote":"Pacote","type":"","descri":""}]},{"date":"08-08-2019","items":[{"id":"3","hrStart":"04 => 00","hrEnd":"07 => 00","hrWork":"03 => 00","nome_user":"Diego ","date":"08-08-2019","cliente":"Marcelo","projeto":"TimeSheet","pacote":"Dashboard","type":"","descri":""}]}]
```

Comment: Ajustar no meu contrller né isso ?

Comment: @DiêgoCorreiadeAndrade Isso mesmo

Comment: Ajustei aqui, porem como devo estruturar o for para era pegar os itens ?