# Método HTTP delete possui corpo?

Tags: http, http-request

Na [documentação da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/DELETE):

> Requisição tem corpo   Não
>
> A resposta bem sucedida tem corpo  Não
>
> Seguro Não
>
> Idempotente    Sim
>
> Cacheável  Não
>
> Aceito nos formulários HTML    Não

Também vi inclusive aqui no site respostas falando que, assim como o GET, o DELETE não possui corpo

Porém fiz um teste com Node.js + Express e Postman. Consegui enviar uma requisição DELETE com um corpo e mostrar no console

Então, afinal, o method HTTP delete possui corpo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possuir, todos possuem¹. O corpo é um atributo de uma abstração superior à entidade da requisição; isto é, toda requisição HTTP é, assim como toda resposta HTTP, uma **mensagem** HTTP e toda mensagem pode ser composta de *start line*, cabeçalhos e corpo.

```
 HTTP-message   = start-line
                  *( header-field CRLF )
                  CRLF
                  [ message-body ]
```

De fato, a única coisa que diferencia uma requisição de uma resposta é apenas a *start line*.

Inclusive, na RFC 7231, que é a especificação mais atual, quando define o [método GET](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1), não cita que este não possui corpo; pelo contrário, ela traz a seguinte citação:

> *A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics; sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing implementations to reject the request.*

Que em tradução livre, seria que a *carga* (corpo) de uma requisição GET não possui semântica definida; uma requisição GET com conteúdo de corpo pode eventualmente ser rejeitada em algumas implementações. Assim, se sua aplicação necessitar de um corpo em uma requisição GET, não há nada de errado.

Um caso simples de visualizar é imaginar que você possui uma rota que traz os produtos vendidos em uma loja virtual:

```
/produtos
```

E você deseja implementar filtros, de modo que consiga selecionar quais os produtos que serão retornados.

```
/produtos?data_cadastro.de=2018-05-01&data_cadastro.ate=2018-05-05
/produtos?preco.ate=100
/produtos?condicao=novo,usado
/produtos?possui_garantia=1
/produtos?nome.contem=camiseta
/produtos?frete_gratis=1
```

E mais uma centena de outros filtros possíveis. Imagine o tamanho da URL para carregar tanta informação assim? Para simplificar, você poderia muito bem passar todas as informações pelo corpo da requisição.

O mesmo acontece com o método DELETE, embora com muito menos frequência, visto que dificilmente você teria tamanha complexidade na exclusão de um recurso, mas, se for necessário, não há problema algum.

---

(1): Todos os métodos possuem corpo, inclusive o HEAD, porém, por definição, qualquer conteúdo presente em seu corpo deve ser ignorado pelo servidor ao gerar a resposta HTTP.

Comment: Nesse não há problema algum, significa que não nenhuma contra indicação? No meu caso eu gostaria de passar o usuário e senha de uma conta para validar a exclusão

Comment: Se você está implementado o servidor, não há problema, pois o servidor saberá o que fazer com o corpo. O que não é recomendado é enviar o corpo em uma requisição sem saber se o recurso no servidor possui suporte, pois se não possuir, a requisição pode ser negada antes mesmo de ser tratada.

Comment: Sim, estou fazendo o back e o front. Apenas por curiosidade (pelo menos por enquanto), como eu faço uma requisição GET passando um corpo e como eu recebo esse corpo no back? Poderia dar um exemplo simples?

Comment: Com PHP, por exemplo, se não estou enganado, pode ser feito com `file_get_contents('php://input')`. Só não tenho certeza se o Apache, por padrão, transfere o corpo da requisição GET ao PHP.

Comment: Sabe como eu poderia passar um copo na requisição com js?