# O Texto de Requisição direta SSL é CONNECT ou GET? (Python + Socket + SSL)

Tags: python, socket, ssl

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import socket, ssl, threading, select

def conecta(c, a):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(('123.456.789.123', 444))
    s = ssl.wrap_socket(s, ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)

    c.recv(8192) # Descarto Requisição Real.


    s.send(b"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n") # Requisição GET.

    s.send(b"CONNECT host:port HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n") # Requisição CONNECT.
```

Qual usar?

Comment: No caso, tanto `CONNECT` quanto `GET` são métodos/verbos HTTP distintos. Isso não tem nada a ver com o Python em si. Não sou acostumado com o verbo `CONNECT` em HTTP, mas o verbo tradicional para "pegar" informações é o `GET`. Para postar é o `POST`, para atualizar é o `PUT` e para corrigir é o `PATCH`.

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/300329/64969 ; a resposta aceita fala até mesmo do método `CONNECT`. Boa leitura

Comment: Estou programando em Python, e por isso o adicionei nas tags. Normalmente eu uso CONNECT quando estou lhe dando com proxy http. Quando estou lhe dando com conexão direta, deixo enviar a requisição real do cliente. Mas e no caso do SSL?