# index indefinido

Tags: php

Estou com um erro de `index` indefinido, já reescrevi o código diversas vezes e nunca encontro o porque do erro, se alguém puder dar uma ajuda. Me desculpe se a pergunta estiver mal formatada, pois sou novo aqui e não aprendi a usar as ferramentas direito

erro:

> Notice: Undefined index: aluno in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\crud-completo\removeAluno.php on line 4
>   {"erro":false,"mensagem":"Aluno removido com sucesso!"}
>
> linha 4: $aluno = json_decode($_POST["aluno"],true);

```
  <?php
    require_once("conexao.php");

    $aluno = json_decode($_POST["aluno"],true);

    $resposta["erro"]=false;
    $resposta["mensagem"]="";

    try{
        $sql="SELECT * FROM aluno WHERE id=:ID";
        $stmt = $conexao->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(":ID", $aluno["id"]);
        $stmt->execute();

        $resultado=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $resposta["data"] = $resultado[0];
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        $resposta["mensagem"] = "Erro ao carregar aluno. <br>{$e->getMessage()}";
        $resposta["erro"]= true;
    }

    echo json_encode($resposta);
?>
```

Comment: Como você está fazendo a requisição? Está usando um `<form method="POST" />`?

Comment: Isto acontece por que ou a requisição para o arquivo PHP não foi feita pelo método POST ou quando não foi enviado nenhum dado cujo nome "aluno".

Comment: ta no form, mas eu nao coloquei o method

Comment: Tente colocar então, `<form action="[ARQUIVO PHP]" method="POST">`. Quando não se insere o método. Então o `form` utiliza o padrão (que é o método GET).

Comment: Para saber mais sobre estes métodos do HTTP: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/300329/m%C3%A9todos-http-na-pr%C3%A1tica