# Redirecionar Rota dentro do Controller informando metodo como POST

Tags: laravel, post, redirecionamento, laravel-rotas, redirect

Tenho um formulario dentro da minha aplicação que deleta um dos elementos trazidos dentro de um select, porem este select mostra 3 tipos diferentes de elementos, então criei uma função que verificaria qual tipo de elemento (utilizando um switch) e redirecionaria para as funções de delete correspondentes. O problema é que ao utilizar os metodos redirect()->route('nome_correspondente'); ele redireciona como "get" que acredito ser o padrão, porêm em minha aplicação estou utilizando Route::post para estas rotas específicas.
Sei que provavelmente há formas teoricamente mais adequadas de realizar este tipo de operação, mas esta duvida provavelmente me assombrará novamente, gostaria muito que alguem conseguisse me informar um jeito de REDIRECIONAR ROTAS ALTERANDO O METODO DELAS DE GET PARA POST.

Codigo de DeletesController@obra

```
   class DeletesController extends Controller
{
    public function obra(Request $request)
    {
        $div = explode('/',$request->obra);
        $id_versao = $div[0];
        $cod_obra = $div[1];
        $type = $div[2];
        $array = [$request];
        switch($type):
            case 'manobra':
                return redirect()->route('delete_manobra',$array);
            break;
            case 'linha':
                return redirect()->route('delete_linha',$array);
            break;
            case 'equipamento':
                return redirect()->route('delete_equipamento',$array);
            break;
        endswitch;
    }
```

Codigo das rotas correspondentes:

```
###############################
//DELETES

Route::post('/SIGET/DeletarObra','App\Http\Controllers\DeletesController@obra')
->name('delete_obra');

Route::post('/SIGET/DeletarModManobra','App\Http\Controllers\DeletesController@manobra')
->name('delete_manobra');

Route::post('/SIGET/DeletarLinha','App\Http\Controllers\DeletesController@linha')
->name('delete_linha');

Route::post('/SIGET/DeletarModEquipamento','App\Http\Controllers\DeletesController@equipamento')
->name('delete_equipamento');
```

Codigo do formulário embora não ache que vá ajudar muito:

```
<p>Caso necessário, você pode excluir uma obra cadastrada erroneamente e cadastra-la novamente.</p>
                <form action="{{route('delete_obra')}}" method="post">
                    @csrf
                    <select name="obra">
                        <option>Obras Cadastradas</option>
                        @foreach ($obras as $value)
                        <option value="{{$value['dados']}}"> {{$value['info']}} </option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                    <button>Excluir</button>
                </form>
```

Exemplo de como fica no html

```
 <p>Caso necessário, você pode excluir uma obra cadastrada erroneamente e cadastra-la novamente.</p>
                <form action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/SIGET/DeletarObra" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="95RqJliXLxWtckCivNFwKNX8ihwKFDzb9IQSrlnt">                    <select name="obra">
                        <option>Obras Cadastradas</option>
                                                <option value="2/24375/manobra"> Mod. Manobra - SE Messias </option>
                                                <option value="2/12345/manobra"> Mod. Manobra - SE Rio Largo </option>
                                                <option value="2/54321/manobra"> Mod. Manobra - PCH Teste </option>
                                            </select>
                    <button>Excluir</button>
                </form>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Recomendo você estudar um pouco sobre **métodos http**, aqui tem respostas muito boas: [Métodos HTTP na prática](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/300329/m%C3%A9todos-http-na-pr%C3%A1tica)

Resumindo, no Laravel, você não vai conseguir acessar um POST diretamente na barra de endereço URL do navegador.
E quando isto é feito:

```
return redirect()->route('delete_equipamento',$array);
```

É o que você está tentando fazer: acessar um POST diretamente na barra de endereço URL do navegador.

> Como é uma rotar de exclusão, o recomendado é se utilizar o method DELETE invés do POST ;)

Tem algumas formas de resolver isso, a que segue mais ou menos a lógica que você quer fazer é utilizar a classe Client para fazer a requisição da url de exclusão:

```php
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
...
$client = new Client();
$response = $client->request('POST', $url, $array); // faz a request para a rota de exclusão
```

Caso queira, é possível acessar os dados da response para fazer alguma validação, por exemplo.

```php
$data = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
if ($data->status != 200) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: https://academy.especializati.com.br/curso/laravel-9-gratuito
Esse curso de Laravel vai te ajudar a entender melhor como as coisas funcionam no framework como um todo.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda e pela indicação de curso, acabei fazendo de uma forma diferente, primeiramente tentei com Middlewares (apenas "organizei" o problema, mas o problema continuo lá), depois fui estudar a documentação da classe que voce indicou, funcionou seguindo seu exemplo como base, mas acabei optando por chamar os metodos de exclusão diretamente dentro do switch ao invés de redirecionar, acredito que assim me confundiria menos na hora de fazer alguma manutenção do código.

Comment: Entendi! Por nada, fico feliz que conseguiu resolver!

Comment: @Gustavo Henrique No trecho "o navegador só consegue acessar o método GET". No meu entendimento isso não é fato. Poderia me indicar onde leu sobre isso?

Comment: @MarcosXavier Até coloquei "resumindo" antes, mas sim, me expressei mal ao utilizar essa expressão. O que quiz dizer é que, no Laravel, ele não vai conseguir acessar aquela url com o method POST através da barra de endereço URL do navegador... Mas vou retificar agora, obrigado!